# `DateTimeFormatter` to handle either a FULL STOP or COMMA in fractional second

Tags: java, parsing, datetime-format, java-time, date-parsing

In the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, how do we specify a formatting pattern for a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) that allows for either a FULL STOP (`.`) (period or dot) or a COMMA (`,`) as the delimiter of a fractional second?

For example, the following works for parsing an input date value ending in either `.0Z` or `,0Z` in `20090813145607.0Z` and `20090813145607,0Z`.

```
String input = "20090813145607.0Z";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMddHHmmss[,S][.S]X" );
```

But for printing, the output contains *both*, generating a repeated pair of fractional seconds.

> 20090813145607,0.0Z

So I deduce I my use of `[,S][.S]` in the formatting pattern is not the correct way to get this functionality.

## `DecimalStyle`

I tried to use the [`DateTimeFormatter::withDecimalStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withDecimalStyle-java.time.format.DecimalStyle-) method passing a [`DecimalStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DecimalStyle.html), but that failed to behave as I expected in my experiments. The documentation does not really explain its intended behavior.

This issue is important as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard recommends using the COMMA but allows the FULL STOP. Either is commonly used in practice.

## `Instant` cannot tolerate a comma

Perhaps this tolerance of comma and/or dot as [decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) is not possible in java.time.

I tried the following code with Java 8 Update 102. The first input with a FULL STOP (dot) succeeds while the second input with a COMMA fails.

```
String inputDot = "2016-01-02T12:34:56.7Z";  // Succeeds.
Instant instantDot = Instant.parse ( inputDot );

String inputComma = "2016-01-02T12:34:56,7Z";  // Fails. Throws a DateTimeParseException.
Instant instantComma = Instant.parse ( inputComma );
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a single `DateTimeFormatter` that can handle both formats for parsing but a single format for formatting?

Comment: I wonder if "DateTimeFormatter" allow such kind of "or" pattern. Two workarounds I can think of is 1. make 2 formatter, one for `,` and one for `.`, if first one failed to parse, use the second one.  Or 2, "normalize" the input by replacing the 3rd-last char with `.` if it is a `,`, and you can use one single formatter

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes I want a single formatter that works for both input and output. I assumed the java.time classes had such bidirectional support for both command & dot, but wrong assumption. See my edit showing that `Instant.parse` can handle dot but not comma.

Comment: @AdrianShum As for normalizing, the comma is preferred by ISO 8601 rather than the dot. Which makes this bug/"feature" all the more surprising. I would have to *denormalize* to a dot as a workaround. And yes, a workaround may be necessary. See my edits with example using `Instant`. So what is the purpose of the [`withDecimalStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withDecimalStyle-java.time.format.DecimalStyle-) method on `DateTimeFormatter`?

Comment: Interesting finding for flawed ISO8601 support in Java time. Will be great if it can be raised as an issue :)

Comment: I filed "Review ID: JI-9042753" on bugs.java.com already. May not appear there until reviewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On dot vs comma, dots are far more common than commas in my experience. [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) uses a dot only as does [XML schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-2-20120405/datatypes.html#rf-lexicalMappings-datetime). The dot is no longer "preferred" (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)):

> A decimal mark, either a comma or a dot (without any preference as
>   stated in resolution 10 of the 22nd General Conference CGPM in
>   2003,[16] but with a preference for a comma according to ISO
>   8601:2004)

Given all this, JSR-310 prefers a dot.

The `DecimalStyle` class does provide some control, where the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFraction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-boolean-) method is used with `true` to output the decimal point from `DecimalStyle`.

To parse either a dot or comma is not possible. This is tracked as [JDK-8132536](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132536), which tackles a general "or" concept in parsing.

Instants are parsed using [`ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) which says that "The localized decimal style is not used".

Thus, the formatters of JSR-310 cannot do what you want.

Comment: About your statement "The dot is no longer preferred", Wikipedia mentions the conference making such a statement happening in 2003, but the official ISO-paper is from 2004, so I think, comma is officially still preferred in context of pure ISO (although even forbidden in ISO-derivates like XML-schema).

Answer (score 1):

```
String fmt1 = "uuuuMMddHHmmss,SX";
String fmt2 = "uuuuMMddHHmmss.SX";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmt1);
TemporalAccessor dateObject = null;
try {
    dateObject = f.parse("20090813145607.0Z");
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmt2);
    try {
        dateObject = f.parse(input);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e1) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid format "+input);
    } 
}
```

Perhaps use a different RuntimeException subclass, but that should sort you.

Answer (score 1):

(Based on my comment in question)

I dbout if "DateTimeFormatter" allow such kind of "or" pattern.

Two workarounds I can think of are

1. make use multiple formatters.  E.g. one for `,` and one for `.`, if first one failed to parse, use the second one.

   pseudo-code

   ```
   List<DateTimeFormatter> formatters = Arrays.asList(
           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss.SX" ),
           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss,SX" ));

   TemporalAccessor result = null;
   for (DateTimeFormatter f: formatters) {
       try {
           result = f.parse(input);
           break;
       } catch(DateTimeParseException ignored) {
       }
   }
   if (result == null) {
       throw new WhateverException();
   }
   ```
2. "Normalize" the input by replacing the 3rd-last char with `.` if it is a `,`, and you can use one single formatter.  E.g.

   ```
   f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss.SX" )
   result = f.parse(input.matches(",..$")
                    ? input.replaceAll("^(.*),(..)$", "\\1.\\2")
                    : input);
   ```