# Comma fails parsing by java.time.Instant

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, java-time, iso8601

This fails:

```
Instant.parse( "2007-12-03T10:15:30,978Z" )  // Fails with comma
```

while this succeeds:

```
Instant.parse( "2007-12-03T10:15:30.978Z" )  // Succeeds with dot
```

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing or generating String representations of date-time values.

The ISO 8601 standard allows either a [COMMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma) or a [FULL STOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) (dot, period) as the [decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) for a fraction-of-second. The [comma is preferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#cite_note-17).

But when I try to [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) from an input string containing a comma, a [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) is thrown. A similar string with a dot instead succeeds.

What is wrong? How do I parse such standard strings containing a comma?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Only dot works in java.time. Just replace comma with dot.

```
"2007-12-03T10:15:30,978Z".replace( "," , "." )
```

## Only dot supported, not comma

In Java 8, the java.time classes expect only a FULL STOP (dot, period) character as the decimal mark.

In most other ways, the java.time classes offer excellent support for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. Fortunately this lacking is easily remedied in your own code. Simply replace any comma with a dot when parsing ISO 8601 strings.

```
String input = "2007-12-03T10:15:30,978Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input.replace( "," , "." ) );
```

Do the reverse to output a String using the preferred comma rather dot. Beware that some protocols and libraries may be biased toward either character.

```
String output = instant.toString().replace( "." , "," ) ;
```

---

For more detailed discussion, see the Question [*`DateTimeFormatter` to handle either a FULL STOP or COMMA in fractional second*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38886005/642706) and the issue page for [JDK-8132536](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8132536)